# Calculating Percentages

Tags: java, percentage

In my Java textbook, they have the following question:

Write an if statement that increases pay by 3% if score is greater than 90, otherwise increases pay by 1%.

And they use the following example:

```
if (score > 90)
  pay *= 1.03;
else
  pay *= 1.01;
```

I am unsure as to where they are getting "1.03" rather than "0.03". I am pretty sure to convert to decimal to percent, you move the decimal 2 places to the left? Am I missing something here?

Comment: You want to add 3% onto the pay, not reduce it to 3%, you do that by multiplying the current pay by 103% which is 1.03

Comment: Move to math.stackexchange.com

Comment: The easy way to test this is to work the textbook's example by hand, then yours and see what the difference is.  But yeah this example is kinda ninth grade algebra.

Comment: Another way to look at it would be if you were using the `+=` operator instead:  `pay += pay * 0.03;`  The example in your book uses one operation (multiplication) whereas `+=` uses two: multiply then add.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is nothing but basic math, the distributive law in action. They are simply adding a percent to the original value. If you want 10% of a number, multiply by 0.1. If you want to **add** 10% to a number, multiply by 1.1. This is the same as

## The distributive law in action:

`number * (1 + 0.1)` is the same as `(number * 1) + (number * 0.1)`

Answer (score 1):

pay + pay*0.3 = pay*(1 + 0.03) = pay*1.03

Also pay *= 1.03; is the exact same thing as saying pay = pay*1.03;